# webpack not able to detect absolute paths alias

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to setup webpack config for my react app. My folder structure is:

```
|--App
  |--webpack.config.js
  |--package.json
  |--src
    |--index.js
    |--Components
      |--Test.js
```

Code in **webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
var DESTINATION_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, 'Build');
var SOURCE_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

module.exports = {
    context: SOURCE_PATH,
    entry: path.join(SOURCE_PATH + '/index.js'),
    output: {
        path: DESTINATION_PATH,
        filename: 'main.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.css$|\.scss$/, loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },
            { test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$|\.woff$|\.ttf$|\.eot$/, loader: "url-loader" },
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/react"]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    mode: 'development',
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
        },
        extensions: [".js", ".json", ".jsx"]
    }
};
```

Code in **index.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Test from 'Component/Test';

ReactDOM.render(<Test/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I get the following error when I run `webpack` command in console:

```
Error: Module not ERROR in ./index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Component/Test' in 'F:\DirName\Solution\POC2\src'
```

I also tried the .env config with plugin [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack). Still get the same error.

I suppose I am not able to form the paths correctly in webpack.config.

Comment: webpack can't find your file. double-check your filestructure. Also, it seems like you have to change your sourcepath to: `app/src`. Can we see your app.js to determine the root of your project?

Comment: @Joel I have not created a file with name `app.js`. I have a `Test.js` for testing.

Comment: Well, your *.js then. Usually called app.js. I.E. the file that you run the node-server through (post it).

Comment: By running node-server, do you mean `ReactDOM.render(<Test/>, document.getElementById('root'));`. If yes, this is in index.js.

Comment: "by running the node-server through", i mean the file that you declare the setup of your node environment through. See my answer below. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I tried the solution below, I replaced `entry` like this `module.exports = {
entry: 'POC2/src/index.js',}`. Now I get this error `Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found.
Alternatively, run 'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info.`

Comment: That's not what I said in the answer. Be so kind to read again.